# How to write/create a text file on a server with the input of a EditText field (plaintext)?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, ftpwebrequest

So I have the function to READ from the server:

```
        btnRead.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            showtxt.Text = ShowRemoteStringFile("ftp://url/text.txt");
        };

    string ShowRemoteStringFile(string readUrl)
    {
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(readUrl);
        req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        WebResponse rsp = (WebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(rsp.GetResponseStream());
        string result = rdr.ReadToEnd();
        return result;
    }
```

Now I'm looking for the write functionality but couldn't find anything.. I tried to connect Web Request with SteamWriter but it's a mess.

I think I have to use a completly different approach than from the read function. Anyone out there that could share his C#, Xamarin genius? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a `FTP` client library, there are plenty of them out there on Nuget/Github/....

Comment: Refer to the official docs from Microsoft on how to use WebRequest to Post data to a server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-send-data-using-the-webrequest-class

Comment: @SushiHangover I found FluentFTP and already tried few things. Thanks a lot for the recommendation! (Y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the System.Net library to do networking. Also you are not doing this async. You should make the button function async as shown below. Just put the contents of your edit box in the string content string. Let me know if you have other questions. I've included using statements too for you. You can get system.http on nuget.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

async Task<string> ShowRemoteStringFile(string readUrl){

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                Convert.ToBase64String(
                    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                        string.Format("{0}:{1}", Username, Password))));
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
var body = new StringContent("your http post body text", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage> r = httpClient.PostAsync("YOUR_URL", body);
// do stuff while waiting for response to come back
var response = await r; //await the request to return a result from the server 
var responseContent = response.Content;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode){
//Do stuff with the response content
}

}
```

Now to make your button async so you can await inside the button event:

```
btnRead.Click += async (sender, e) => 
{
    await ShowRemoteStringFile("string"); 
};
```

Let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot.